# ¿Cómo cambiar la intensidad de vibración en Android?

Tags: android

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Android Studio. Ya sé como hacer que un botón libere una vibración$.

Mi duda es si existe o hay una manera de poder cambiar la intensidad de la vibració$n. Es decir, en el código anterior se le aplica la duración de la vibración$, ahora lo que necesito es manipular la intensidad de la vibración$. Por así decirlo disminuir la intensidad de la vibración$.

```
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Vibrate in milliseconds
            //For example 2000 milliseconds is 2 seconds
            vibrator.vibrate(1000);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Revisando la documentación oficial se puede modificar los tipos de vibración y tiempos pero no la intensidad. Dejo la fuente donde lo he revisado: [Documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Existe o hay una manera de poder cambiar la intensidad de la
>   vibración.

Actualmente **no hay manera de cambiar la intensidad de la vibración** programaticamente.

Lo único que puedes cambiar es el [patrón de vibración](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) modificando el tiempo y la amplitud, pero esto a partir de Android 8.0.

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        long[] time = {0, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100};
        int[] amplitude = {0, 50, 0, 100, 0, 150};
        VibrationEffect vibrationEffect = VibrationEffect.createWaveform(time, amplitude, -1 /*-1 No repeat*/);
        vibrator.vibrate(vibrationEffect);
    }else{
        vibrator.vibrate(1000);
    }
```